Spring Resource Server not adding Gateway prefix
My Swagger link works:
http://localhost:7080/bff/api/v1/resource/swagger-ui.html

But it forwards to:
location:
/api/v1/resource/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html

which links to:
Request URL:
http://localhost:7080/api/v1/resource/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html

(as it misses /bff, I keep getting back 404 Not Found)
I can see my BFF forwarding the right headers in the request to the Resource Server:
Forwarded: proto=http;host="localhost:7080";for="127.0.0.1:51801"
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Prefix: /bff
X-Forwarded-Port: 7080
X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:7080
host: localhost:9090
content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer eyJhb...

Why do the swagger generated re-directs not add the X-Forwarded-Prefix?
How can I manually through code force this?
UPDATE:
I've further raised the issue with Spring Boot...
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/42317
(some of them are helpful, others much less so...)
Appreciate direction from anyone as to where I might be going wrong.
